# How to random range can stop when the index matches the input and without duplicate question display?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random

In the following code I have an array to store questions. I want to make it appear random when the game starts. Using `questionIndex = Random.Range(0, questionPool.Length);` managed to do so, but there is still duplication and does not stop right according to the index.

```
void Start()
{
    audioPlayer = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
    dataController = FindObjectOfType<DataController>();

    currentRoundData = dataController.GetCurrentRoundData();
    questionPool = currentRoundData.questions;

    timeRemaining = currentRoundData.timeLimitInSeconds;
    UpdateTimeRemainingDisplay();
    Time.timeScale = 1f;
    playerScore = 0;
    questionIndex = 0;

    ShowQuestion();
    isRoundActive = true;
}

void ShowQuestion()
{
    RemoveAnswerButtons();

    questionIndex = Random.Range(0, questionPool.Length);
    QuestionData questionData = questionPool[questionIndex];
    questionText.text = questionData.questionText;

    for (int i = 0; i < questionData.answers.Length; i++)
    {
        GameObject answerButtonGameObject = answerButtonObjectPool.GetObject();
        answerButtonGameObjects.Add(answerButtonGameObject);
        answerButtonGameObject.transform.SetParent(answerButtonParent);
        answerButtonGameObject.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;

        AnswerButton answerButton = answerButtonGameObject.GetComponent<AnswerButton>();
        answerButton.SetUp(questionData.answers[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem: "there is still duplication" and "doesn't stop right." Can you provide more information? It is not obvious what is duplicated or what is supposed to stop. It would be helpful if you could describe what you expect this code to do and what it actually does that is wrong.

Comment: You probably want to research how to *shuffle* a collection

Comment: Would you like to pick a single random question from collection or do you want to randomize/shuffle the entire collection and display them all ?

Comment: @JohnWu I made a game quiz that has 10 questions. I tried to display the 10 questions randomly not sequentially. so I added questionIndex = Random.Range (0, questionPool.Length); in my code. from the code successfully made the 10 questions appear randomly. but when the game is played, which is supposed to display 10 questions, he stops before all the questions appear. sometimes all the questions appear but the questions keep appearing more than 10 questions. how can I make 10 questions appear randomly without duplicating questions and finishing when 10 questions have been answered

Comment: @AnuViswan yes I want to randomize all the questions I entered, and display them all. and when all appearances the game is complete.

Comment: Just sort the list randomly, e.g. `var questionPool = questionPool.OrderBy( x => Guid.NewGuid() ).ToList();` Or if you want to be extremely efficient, use the shuffle algorithm Anu provided, although IMO that is a bit of an overkill unless you have thousands of questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following extension method to Randomize collection

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Shuffle<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> dataArray)
{
    var dataArrayList = dataArray.ToList();
    var returnValue = Enumerable.Empty<TSource>();
    for (int index = dataArrayList.Count()-1; index > 0; index--)
    {
        var randomKey = _randomGenerator.Next(1, index);
        var temp = dataArrayList[randomKey];
        dataArrayList[randomKey] = dataArrayList[dataArray.Count() - 1];
        dataArrayList[dataArray.Count() - 1] = temp;
    }
    return dataArrayList;
}
```

You can now use the extension as

```
var shuffledQuestionPool = questionPool.Shuffle();
```